# SSL not working after Generalizing Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, load-balancing, autoscaling

I configured SSL on my original Windows 2016 server test website to work with HTTPS traffic.

After generalizing the VM, when I created a new Windows VM from the generalized VHD, I'm unable to browse through HTTPS traffic.

When I tried to edit the Binding for HTTPS, I got the following error:

*A specified logon session does not exist.It may have already been terminated.Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520*

What steps do I have to follow before generalizing the Windows VM so that the above error doesn't occur.

As I would using that VHD for Autoscaling, I can't RDP and resolve this issue on every VM launched under Autoscaling.

Please help me.

Comment: Have anyone faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my SSL issue on my Windows VHD for Azure Autoscaling by using running  scheduled task on startup on the below given powershell script to install the SSL.

[restore-certificates.ps1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/30-25800-132859-2520/restore-certificates.ps1)

[write-applicationeventlog.ps1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/30-25800-132859-2521/write-applicationeventlog.ps1)

Just follow the steps given inside restore-certificates.ps1 file and create a Scheduled task using **System user** and select **Run whether user is logged in or not** in the General options.

Answer (score 3):

Error HRESULT: [0x80070520](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/10/07/error-hresult-0x80070520-when-adding-ssl-binding-in-iis/)

1. Check the "Allow this certificate to be exported" checkbox when import the pfx with IIS UI
2. Issue the CA to FQDN name
3. Import the CA with mmc instead of IIS UI

Check: certutil -v -store my cert_hash_of_non_working_cert  (e.g. certutil -v -store my aac000ba4d663753ecbc80c082fd1feb2e2b4a11)

and check for Key containers / Unique container name IDs. If you can find files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys with name equivalent to key container id check for the ACLs.

Additional information: [Refer here](https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO22115&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1435162914930)

Comment: I tried to importing SSL certificate MMC and followed the steps from your refer here link, but still it did not load the https traffic.
Had to delete the certificate and do the binding again in order to work again.
Are there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Are you getting same error while loading the https traffic?

Comment: yes I got the same error, had to delete the certificate and insatll it again so that it could load https traffic.